# What is the possessive case and the objective case of "ye?"

Tags: personal-pronouns, grammatical-case, early-modern-english, possessive-determiners, objective-case

I know very well that archaically, "thou" is the nominative case for the modern day "you" while "thee" is the accusative case and that there is no distinction between the nominative and accusative cases in modern English, (both "you.") I know the same for "I" and "me," "he" and "him," "she" and "her," "we" and "us," and "they" and "them," nominative and accusative respectively. However, I have scoured the Earth looking for the accusative (objective) case of "ye." I have just been assuming that it was simply just "ye," but I am searching for a definitive answer. Similarly, what is the possessive case of "ye?" Essentially, what is the word for "to all of you" and "all of your" in archaic times (the second person plural accusative and possessive pronouns?)

Comment: It’s almost too obvious, but it’s simply _you_ and _your_. At least originally; there was a period of change when _ye_ was also used both as subject and object, singular and plural, before the old accusative plural eventually took over the whole business. And of course there are dialects which now use _ye_ for the plural (both cases) and _you_ for the singular, which is historically ridonkulous, but perfectly common.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Peculiar mix of "ye" and "you"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/379674/peculiar-mix-of-ye-and-you)

Comment: You are missing the fact that "thou", "thee" and "thine" were the informal singular pronouns similar to the French "tu" and its related pronouns while "you" "ye" and "your" were the plural and formal pronouns similar to the French "vous" and its related pronouns. Formal English has only had one set of pronouns for the second person for a couple of centuries and "ye" was dropped about the same time.

Comment: @BoldBen It’s not stated outright in the question, but the way I read it, Leo does understand that _thou_ was singular and _ye_ was plural (the informal/formal distinction may be a different matter).

Answer (score 15):

In [Early Modern English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ye_(pronoun)#Etymology), ***ye*** was the nominative case and the objective and possessives were the familiar ***you*** (objective), ***your*** (possessive determiner) and ***yours*** (possessive pronoun).

Comment: Really informative answer   ....For me, this website is the intellectual equivelent of standing in a room naked with a bunch of adult movie stars. My brain feels limp and useless lol. I can speak English, but clearly from reading your answer I don't know much about it.

Answer (score 6):

> Genesis 18:5 And I will fetch a morsel of bread, and comfort **ye**
>   **your** hearts; after that **ye** shall pass on: for therefore are **ye** come to **your** servant.

Here is an example from the Bible showing all versions in a single sentence.

Comment: Which is which case?

Comment: All versions… except the object form which is the main point in this question.

Comment: It looks like the first _ye_ is the indirect object of _comfort_, if _I_ (i.e, God) is still the subject of _comfort_, saying "(I will) comfort ye your hearts". It's strange to see a nominative in that position.

Comment: This is a useful answer because it demonstrates the nominative and objective uses.

Comment: @JohnLawler: [It looks like](https://biblehub.com/genesis/18-5.htm) the verb rendered as "comfort" is an _imperative_ in the Hebrew original (Vulgate has an imperative too), so this "ye" is probably an honest nominative.

Comment: KJV Genesis 17:11 has all three of the English cases for _ye_: _And **ye** shall circumcise the flesh of **your** foreskin; and it shall be a token of the covenant betwixt me and **you**._

Comment: @JesseSteele As others have pointed it, the sentence is actually missing the objective case.

Comment: @MarkBeadles okay, I see that and I stand corrected. But, it does show how the nominative and possessive work together by providing contrast, especially since the possessive is normal today. It's not the main answer, but it does contribute to the knowledge. That's my point, and thanks for the correction. ;-)